# Unity - Raycast not working when more than one prefab on Scene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, monodevelop

I created a script that uses RayCasting for detecting two Prefabs - One prefab has a tag called "target" and the second prefab has a tag called "unTarget". On click on prefab 1 with "Target" tag its supposed to increment count and when clicking on prefab 2 with "unTarget" tag its supposed to decrement the count. This seems to work when only one Prefab is in the scene. It will increment/decrement when only one is added and clicked. When both prefabs are in the Scene both prefabs will increment. I am not sure why this is happening. Any Help or Ideas? Sorry if my code is a bit messy.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class clicks : MonoBehaviour 
{

    public int score;  

    void Start()
    {
        score = 0;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update() 
    { 
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) 
        {

            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            RaycastHit hit;

            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit,200))
            {
                if (GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("target"))
                {
                    score++;
                }
                else 
                {
                    score--;
                }
            }
      }
}
```

Comment: Also, it's much easier to just implement IPointerClickHandler than manually raycasting stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag` method is going to look at your entire scene for an object with `target` as the tag.  Since you have one in the scene that will always return true, if you hit something.

You need to look at the properties on the RaycastHit and pull the tag from there.

```
if (hit.collider.tag == "target") 
{
   score++;
} 
else 
{
   score--;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not hit.collider.name == "target"? Hit just returns the ray doesn't it?

Comment: Unity docs are blocked at my worksite.  I'm confident about the GameObject static call, but not so much on pulling data out of the rayhit.  does collider have a reference to its gameobject  `hit.collider.gameObject.Tag` maybe?

Comment: Phone to the rescue.  Followed docs and added the correct path through the properties attached to the return value